Cannot get Client certification authentication working with Tomcat 9
I am trying to enable client-authentication on a Tomcat 9.0.90 instance (running on Windows).
I was able to easily get server-authenticated/1-way SSL working, but I have been struggling to get the client-authentication working.
I am testing by using:
openssl s_client -connect <host>:8443 -debug

and then looking for the list of acceptable CAs messages, but I only see:
No client certificate CA names sent

Here's the configuration for the 8443 port in server.xml:
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxParameterCount="1000"
           >
    <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/CERTS/tcat.xxx.com.jks"
         certificateKeystorePassword="password"
                     type="RSA"
                     certificateKeyAlias="tcat.xxx.com"
                     truststoreFile="conf/CERTS/JLCA.jks"
                     truststorePass="password"
                     truststoreType="JKS"
         clientAuth="true"
                     certificateVerification="required"
                     />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>

It's been a while since I've worked with Tomcat, but I don't remember ever having so much difficulty getting this (client authentication) set up before :( !!!
Can any one tell me what the problem might be??
Thanks,
Jim
P.S.  FYI, I actually started this whole exercise with Tomcat 10.1.25, but it got so messed up, I decided to try Tomcat 9, because I saw some posts that said it was easier to get working.  At this point, I'd really just like to get the client cert working :)... I don't have any specific requirement for any version of Tomcat.
EDIT:  I was just doing more testing and noticed these lines in the catalina log file during the Tomcat startup:
WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin Match [Server/Service/Connector/SSLHostConfig/Certificate] failed to set property [truststoreFile] to [conf/CERTS/JLCA.jks]
02-Jul-2024 23:47:27.543 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin Match [Server/Service/Connector/SSLHostConfig/Certificate] failed to set property [truststorePassword] to [password]
02-Jul-2024 23:47:27.543 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin Match [Server/Service/Connector/SSLHostConfig/Certificate] failed to set property [truststorePass] to [password]
02-Jul-2024 23:47:27.544 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin Match [Server/Service/Connector/SSLHostConfig/Certificate] failed to set property [truststoreType] to [JKS]
02-Jul-2024 23:47:27.544 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin Match [Server/Service/Connector/SSLHostConfig/Certificate] failed to set property [clientAuth] to [required]

Does anyone know if that is "normal", and also is it saying that those properties are not being set, and, if so, "Why not?"???
EDIT 2:  I was checking the tomcat /manager app and when I click on "Trusted certificates per Connector", it is saying:
Connector["https-openssl-nio-8443"]-_default_  ==> Certificate information cannot be obtained from this connector at runtime

EDIT 3: Made changes per dave_thompson:
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true"
           scheme="https" secure="true"
           maxParameterCount="1000"
           >
    <SSLHostConfig   
                     truststoreFile="conf/CERTS/JLCA.jks"
                     truststorePassword="password"
                     truststorePass="password"
                     truststoreType="JKS"
         certificateVerification="optional"
         >
        <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/CERTS/tcat.xxx.com.jks"
         certificateKeystorePassword="password"
                     type="RSA"
                     certificateKeyAlias="tcat.xxx.com"
                     />
    </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>

and it worked - openssl s_client has:
Acceptable client certificate CA names
/C=US/O=JLO/OU=JLOU/CN=JLCA

ALSO slightly off-topic there was another, unrelated problem - because I am running Tomcat as a service, it does not use setenv.bat, so I had to use an app, tomcat9w.exe, to edit to select the JDK 11 JVM.

Not programming or development but: truststore* and clientVerification are on SSLHostConfig not Certificate and clientAuth is obsolete; before 8.5 it was used on Connector only in JSSE mode (while APR used SSLVerifyClient)

dave_thompson - are you suggesting truststore* and clientverification to the sslhostconfig (and remove clientAuth?  FYI, I am going to post some additional info I just found and then try that.

YAHOO!!!  It works.  dave_thompson can you make your command an answer and then I can mark it !!

@dave_thompson_085 - can you make your comment to an answer so that I can mark it answered?  Thanks!
